# Regular expression for matching a directory but not the files inside?

Tags: regex, analytics, directory

Trying to create a segment for a specific folder but not for the urls inside it.

with this expression:

domain.com/folders/([\w|-]*)

I select up to the folder /dw-rs/

https://domain.com/folders/dw-rs/

but it also selects all files after the folder like:

https://domain.com/folders/dw-rs/adfasfsfa45

How can i make it stop at the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Just append the end-of-line-matching operator "$":

`domain.com/folders/([\w|-]*)$`